Harano Aji Gothic font not working in this MWE
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, twoside, margin=1in, top=0.9in, bottom=1in, left=0.9in, right=0.7in]{geometry}

% Japanese Language Support
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\japanesefont[RawFeature={+tlig}]{HaranoAjiGothic-Regular}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % Remove section numbering

\begin{document}

{\japanesefont これはテストです。}

{\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}\selectfont\noindent % Dramatically increase font size
これはテストです。
}

{\fontspec[FakeBold=6.0]{Harano Aji Gothic} % Change font and apply strong FakeBold
\fontsize{18pt}{22pt}\selectfont\noindent
これは別のテストです。 % Japanese text
}

\end{document}

The output image is as follows:

The Harano Aji Gothic font is not being used.
I am compiling using lualatex in MacTex on MacOS (all latest versions within the last month or so). Here is the log file output:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.4.26)  3 MAY 2024 01:50
 restricted system commands enabled.
**zz.tex
(./zz.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/angelx/Library/texlive/2024/
texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/angelx/Library/texlive/2024/
texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/local/texlive/202
4/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /Users/angelx/Library/texlive/
2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count186
\c@chapter=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\c@figure=\count193
\c@table=\count194
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count195
\Gm@cntv=\count196
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count197
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen140
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen144
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen145
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen147
\Gm@dimlist=\toks18
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty
Package: luatexja 2024-02-19 Japanese Typesetting with Lua(La)TeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty
Package: luatexja-core 2023-04-06 Core of LuaTeX-ja

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count198
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable14
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks20
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks21
)
\XKV@depth=\count199
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count266
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty
Package: svn-prov 2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
)
Package: everyhook 2014/11/26 v1.2 (SVN Rev: 12)\ Hooks for low level TeX every
X primitives.
\everypar=\toks22
\frozen@everymath=\toks23
\frozen@everydisplay=\toks24
\everyhbox=\toks25
\everyvbox=\toks26
\everycr=\toks27
)
...
...
Custom whatsit ja_al_boundary = 6(load cache: ltj-cid-auto-adobe-japan1.luc)
Lua module: luatexja.charrange 2022-08-19 Handling the range of Japanese charact
ers
Lua module: luatexja.stack 2022-08-20 LuaTeX-ja stack system
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' in `vpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' in `pre_output_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.lineskip' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.lineskip' in `append_to_vlist_filter'.
Lua module: luatexja.jfont 2023-04-06 Loader for Japanese fonts
Removing  `luaotfload.define_font' from `define_font'.
Inserting `luatexja.font_callback' in `define_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' in `luatexja.define_font'.(load cache: extra_
lmroman10-regular.luc)
Inserting `ltj.get_vert_form' in `luatexja.define_jfont'.
Removing  `ltj.prepare_extra_data' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.supply_tounicode' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.process_input_buffer' in `process_input_buffer'.
Inserting `ltj.hyphenate' in `hyphenate'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Lua module: luatexja.jfmglue 2022-08-29 Insertion process of JFM glues, [x]kanji
skip and others
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info' in `luatexja.jfmglue.whatsit_getinfo'.
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info_after' in `luatexja.jfmglue.whatsit_after'.
Inserting `ltj.mlist_to_hlist_pre' in `pre_mlist_to_hlist_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.set_stack_level' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.main' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.set_stack_level' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.main' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' in `hpack_filter'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty
Package: ltj-base 2021-03-16
...
\ltj@@lua@uncopycheckdir@inner=\luafunction52
\ltj@@lua@uncopy@restore@whatsit@inner=\luafunction53
(load cache: ltj-kinsoku_default.luc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty
Package: ltj-latex 2022-10-15 LaTeX support of LuaTeX-ja
Inserting `ltj.direction' in `pre_shipout_filter'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty
Package: lltjfont 2023-04-13 Patch to NFSS2 for LuaTeX-ja
\ltj@@latex@plv=\count273

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX file
\@remove@tlig@@@=\luafunction54
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 105.
)
...
\zstrutbox=\box54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \strut on input line 91.
\ltj@@add@fenc@@inner=\luafunction55
...
\ltj@@adjust@baseline@inner=\luafunction64
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontencoding on input line 646.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontfamily on input line 689.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontseries on input line 923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontseriesforce on input line 924.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontshape on input line 944.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontshapeforce on input line 955.
\ltj@@jfont@@jfmonly@@inner=\luafunction65
\ltj@@does@alt@set@@inner=\luafunction66
\ltj@@cipath@clear@inner=\luafunction67
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty
Package: lltjdefs 2022-01-23 Default font settings of LuaTeX-ja
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 79.

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 79.
(load cache: extra_haranoajimincho-regular.luc)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua)
\symmincho=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mincho' in version `bold'
(Font)                  JY3/mc/m/n --> JY3/gt/m/n on input line 88.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty
Package: lltjcore 2023-02-26 Patch to LaTeX2e Kernel for LuaTeX-ja

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-02-20 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-02-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count274
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
))
\@tombowwidth=\dimen163
\@TL=\box56
...
\@CR=\box67
(load cache: extra_lmmono9-regular.luc)
\@bannertoken=\toks28
\@@paperheight=\dimen164
\@@paperwidth=\dimen165
\@@topmargin=\dimen166
LaTeX Info: Redefining \underline on input line 283.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-atbegshi.
sty
Package: lltjp-atbegshi 2022-08-12 Patching \shipout hooks for LuaTeX-ja
\l__platex_shipout_dummy_box=\box68
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.
sty
Package: lltjp-geometry 2021-10-24 Patch to geometry for LuaTeX-ja with vertica
l writing mode
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)))
\ltj@temp@cctb=\catcodetable16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty
Package: luatexja-compat 2020-08-08 Compatibility with pTeX
(load cache: ltj-jisx0208.luc)
\hour=\count275
\minute=\count276
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2024-02-18 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2024/02/13 2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2024/02/13 v2.9a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count277
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count278
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count279
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count280
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count281
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count282
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count283
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count284
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count285
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count286
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count287
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen167
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen168
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen169

(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 112.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)(load cache:
 extra_lmroman10-bold.luc)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `JT3/gt/m/n' tried instead on input line 3934.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/gt/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 3934.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `JY3/gt/m/n' tried instead on input line 3934.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/gt/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 3934.
(load cache: extra_haranoajigothic-medium.luc)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-fontspec.
sty)
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /Users/angelx/Library/texlive/2024
/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.(load cache: e
xtra_haranoajigothic-regular.luc)

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "HaranoAjiGothic-Regular/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "HaranoAjiGothic-Regular/B" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "HaranoAjiGothic-Regular/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).

luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'HaranoAjiGothic-Regular(0)' created for
(fontspec)             font 'HaranoAjiGothic-Regular' with options
(fontspec)             [RawFeature={+tlig}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:HaranoAjiGothic-Regular:mode=node;script=latn;l
anguage=dflt;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

 (./zz.aux)
\openout1 = zz.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
3.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for JY3/mc/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for JT3/mc/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: luatex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(65.04256pt, 317.98866pt, 50.58878pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(65.04256pt, 513.11745pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=433.62pt
* \paperheight=650.43pt
* \textwidth=317.98866pt
* \textheight=513.11745pt
* \oddsidemargin=-7.22743pt
* \evensidemargin=-21.68121pt
* \topmargin=-37.29492pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=125.0pt
* \marginparsep=7.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 13.
...
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 13.
(load cache: extra_lmroman17-regular.luc)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 23.09326pt on input line 17.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 23.09326pt on input line 17.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "HaranoAjiGothic/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).

(load cache: extra_haranoajigothic-bold.luc)

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "HaranoAjiGothic/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | aux : font no 23 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : font no 28 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script latn
 with language dflt

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'HaranoAjiGothic(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'Harano Aji Gothic' with options [FakeBold=6.0].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:HaranoAjiGothic:mode=node;script=latn;language=
dflt;embolden=6.0;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:HaranoAjiGothic/B:mode=node;script=latn;languag
e=dflt;embolden=6.0;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 17.31995pt on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 17.31995pt on input line 22.
(save cache: /Users/angelx/Library/texlive/2024/texmf-var/luatexja/extra_lmroman
slant10-regular.lua.gz)(save cache: /Users/angelx/Library/texlive/2024/texmf-var
/luatexja/extra_lmromanslant10-regular.luc)
LaTeX Font Info:    Kanji font shape `JY3/mc/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              No change on input line 26.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

]
(./zz.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
...
 32 fonts using 50438095 bytes
 110i,5n,115p,1846b,288s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/haranoaji/HaranoAjiMin
cho-Regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmr
oman10-regular.otf>
Output written on zz.pdf (1 page, 6698 bytes).

PDF statistics: 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)

